# NRF24L01+ - After stopListening, can't write data

Tags: serial, nrf24l01+

Okay so this is the code for my receiver.

This is quite confusing so let's dub Receiver = `DEVICE 1` and Transmitter = `DEVICE 2`

`DEVICE 1`: NRF24L01+, HC-05 (Bluetooth)

`DEVICE 2`: NRF24L01+

So `DEVICE 1` will receive data from `DEVICE 2`. Also When it receives data from my phone that is connected to the HC-05 module, it will `radio.StopListening` and `radio.write`.

But for some reason, after i do `radio.StopListening`, `radio.write` doesnt work.

Currently, `DEVICE 2` has a very simple code to receive data being sent from `DEVICE 1`. I've done this just to check if there's any data being sent when `DEVICE 1`'s HC-05 module receives data.

Code:

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <printf.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>

RF24 radio(9, 8);

byte addresses[][6] = {"1Node","2Node"};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_2MBPS);
  radio.setChannel(124);

  // Open a writing and reading pipe on each radio, with opposite addresses
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[1]);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned char rf_data; //Make a variable to store the data
  unsigned char bt_data;
  unsigned char tosend;
  radio.startListening();

  if (radio.available()){
    while (radio.available()){
      radio.read(&rf_data, sizeof(rf_data));
      Serial.println(rf_data);
      }
    }

  if (Serial.available()>0){
    while (Serial.available()>0){
      bt_data = Serial.read();
      radio.stopListening();
      Serial.println(bt_data); //----------- I'M ABLE TO SERIAL PRINTLN ----
      radio.write(&bt_data, sizeof(bt_data)); //-------- BUT I'M UNABLE TO PERFORM THIS CODE HERE FOR SOME REASON
      }
    }

}
```

I've added comments to show which part works and which part doesn't

I hope this question isn't too hard to understand.

Comment: naming the Receiver  `DEVICE 1` is less confusing?

Comment: @jsotola cant u be a bit more helpful

Comment: Are the example sketches working? Maybe you have an issue that is not related to your code.

Answer (score 1):

There could be few reasons but, firstly I would like to ask you to check if your write command is working at all. Try to disable reading mode and leave just write mode:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <printf.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>

RF24 radio(9, 8);

byte addresses[][6] = {"1Node","2Node"};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_2MBPS);
  radio.setChannel(124);

  // Open a writing and reading pipe on each radio, with opposite addresses
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]);
  //radio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[1]);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned char rf_data; //Make a variable to store the data
  unsigned char bt_data;
  unsigned char tosend;
  //radio.startListening();

 // if (radio.available()){
 //   while (radio.available()){
 //     radio.read(&rf_data, sizeof(rf_data));
 //     Serial.println(rf_data);
 //    }
 //   }

  if (Serial.available()>0){
    while (Serial.available()>0){
      bt_data = Serial.read();
      //radio.stopListening();
      Serial.println(bt_data); //----------- I'M ABLE TO SERIAL PRINTLN ----
      radio.write(&bt_data, sizeof(bt_data)); //-------- BUT I'M UNABLE TO PERFORM THIS CODE HERE FOR SOME REASON
      }
    }

}
```

Try above code and if it will not work change `RF24_2MBPS` to `RF24_1MBPS` and `RF24_PA_MIN` to `RF24_PA_LOW` on both modules (transmitter and receiver)